# How to realize the DRAWING processing in Processing?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, drawing, processing, linear-algebra

We all know how to draw a line in Processing.

But when we draw a line, the line is shown immediately.

What if i want to witness the drawing process, namely, to see the line moving forward, gradually completes a whole line.

Here's what i want to realize: to DRAW several lines and curves which finally turn into some pattern.

So how to make that happen? Using array?

Many thanks.

Comment: In processing, lines are drawn immediately. If you want to draw it in pieces, you must draw many little lines that make up the larger line. One way to do it is what manofstone suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In processing all of the drawing happens in a loop. An easy way to create animated sequences like you describe is to use frameCount to drive it and using the modulus function % is a good way to create a loop. For example, to animate along the x axis:

```
void draw() {
   float x = 50;
   float y = 50;
   float lineLength = 50;
   int framesToAnimate = 60;
   line(x,y,x+float(frameCount % framesToAnimate)/framesToAnimate*lineLength, y);
}
```

Note: strange things will happen if you don't cast / convert to a float

I use this pretty often to animate other features such as the color.

```
fill(color(127 + sin(float(frameCount)/90)*127, 0, 0, 127));
```

If you want to get more advanced, setting vectors and coordinates with [PVector](http://processing.org/reference/PVector.html). There is a pretty good tutorial on [Daniel Shiffman's site](http://www.shiffman.net/teaching/nature/vectors/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your animation independent of frame rate, you can use mills() instead. That will return current time since the sketch started so you can set something to happen in a given time in seconds.
like for example:

```
long initialTime;

void setup(){
size(400,200);
initialTime = millis();
}
void draw() {
float x = 50;
float y = 50;                              //set the multiplier to adjust speed
line(x,y,x+(millis()-initialTime)*0.01, y);           //10 px/sec
line(x,y+50,x+(millis()-initialTime)*0.05, y+50);     //50 px/sec
line(x,y+100,x+(millis()-initialTime)*0.001, y+100);  // 1 px/sec
 }
```

There is also some animation libraries, i've seen some impressive results with some, but i never used them. Here a [list](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/#animation).